# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method when converting Nullable DateTime

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I'm trying to get the Day of the week from a Nullable DateTime and then Joining on a list of days.

My solution was to convert it to a DateTime first, but Linq to Entities doesn't like it.

LIST is an `IEnumerable<string>`

suggestions?

```
        var result = from X in model.X
                     where X.StartDate.HasValue
                     join item in LIST on
                        Convert.ToDateTime(X.StartDate).DayOfWeek.ToString() equals item
                     select X;
```

Converting to a methods chain is no help:

```
var result = model.X.Where(x => x.StartDate.HasValue).Join(LIST,x => Convert.ToDateTime(x.StartDate).DayOfWeek.ToString(), item => item, (x, item) => x);
```

Comment: linq to entities does not support these Convert.Todatetime(),tryparse()..this works well in linq to sql.....

Comment: And you cant join with a list in linq-to-entities

Comment: How about `X.StartDate.Value` instead of `Convert.ToDateTime(X.StartDate)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.ToString() is not supported by Linq-To-Entities, as are a number of other extension methods.

The short (and probably inaccurate to some degree) reason is that the .ToString() in the context above is sent to Sql Server to run in a query.  Sql Server has no idea what .ToString() is, and so it fails when Sql Server's query parser tries to execute it.

also, FYI

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738550.aspx

Answer (score 2):

```
var result = from X in model.X
             where X.StartDate.HasValue && 
                   List.Contains(SqlFunctions.DatePart("weekday", X.StartDate))
             select X;
```

`weekday` returns an `int` so you should have a list of integers not strings

Comment: +1, but be careful - the value returned by `DATEPART` will change if the server's `@@DATEFIRST` has been modified.  You can also use `SqlFunctions.DateName` to get the day of the week as a string.

Comment: Your right, but if you use DateName you have to worry about culture

Comment: Hi i m using this but getting error NotSupportedException: Method 'System.Nullable`1[System.Int32] IsNumeric(System.String)' has no supported translation to SQL.] in my code what to do next to resolve this .

Answer (score 1):

this will work if you use `.ToList()` before the convertion take place.
[Entity 4.0 Casting Value As DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4349188/entity-4-0-casting-value-as-datetime/8995928#8995928)

```
var result = model.X.Where(x => x.StartDate.HasValue).ToList().Join(LIST,x => Convert.ToDateTime(x.StartDate).DayOfWeek.ToString(), item => item, (x, item) => x);
```

Comment: this will "make it work", but your link explains it best:  "the downside is when you call .ToList() this will bring all the data from db and then do the conversion in host side instead of database side"  --not exactly what I was after.

Answer (score 0):

### **EDIT:** Do not use this code. It has been left here to show you what will *not* work and so you can see Chris' reasons why and how to solve.

Untested:

```
    var result = from X in model.X
                 where ((X.StartDate != null) && X.StartDate.HasValue)
                 join item in LIST on
                    Convert.ToDateTime(X.StartDate).DayOfWeek.ToString() equals item
                 select X;
```

If you have declared `StartDate` as a `Nullable` field, it follows you should check for null values.

Comment: What's the difference between `X.StartDate != null` and `X.StartDate.HasValue`?

Comment: Ask yourself this: What properties does `null` have? @KevinDeus: It is simple enough to try and see.

Comment: Are you suggesting that is `X.StartDate` is null then you can't get its `HasValue` property? If so, I suggest you try it yourself with a `DateTime?` instance.

Comment: I dont need to run that query, LinqToEntities doesn't like .ToString().  its not supported